# How to call (make visible) variable from another class?

Tags: c#

I want to create an `ArrayList` in `Student class` but  can't add to it - `student1, student2, student3` values from `Main`. How can I make student1/2/3 make visible without replacing them to other class?
This is the part of my code:

```
    public class Program
    {

     static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Student student1 = new Student("John", "Grodinskiy", "12/07/1996", "Lesy Ukrainky 88", "Cherkasy", "58000", "Ukraine");
        Student student2 = new Student("Niko", "Rekun", "03/02/1995", "Promyslova 86", "Velykiy Bychkiv", "90615","Ukraine");
        Student student3 = new Student("Veronica","Kran", "26/03/1991", "Uzhgorodska 1", "Svalyava", "59432", "Ukraine");
        ........
Console.WriteLine("The {0} program contains the {1} of Sciense degree\nThe {2} of Sciense degree contains the course {3}\n{4} course contains {5} students", program.Program_name1, myDegree.degree_name, myDegree.degree_name, myCourse.Course_name, myCourse.Course_name, Student.Counter);
        student1.TakeTest();
        student2.TakeTest();
        student3.TakeTest();
    }

}
```

//Class

```
    public class Student:Person
    {
        public Student(string name, string last_name, string birthday, string address, string city, string zip, string country)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Last_name = last_name;
            this.Birth_date = birthday;
            this.Address = address;
            this.City = city;
            this.Zip = zip;
            this.Country = country;
            Counter++
        }

        public void TakeTest()
        {
            Take_counter++;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} student took the test.",Take_counter);
        }

        public void add_student()
        {
             ArrayList students = new ArrayList();
             students.Add(student1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` (which stores everything as an object) - use a generic collection such as `List<T>` eg. `List<Student> students = new List<Student>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below part of your code, does not belong in the `Student` class.

```
public void add_student()
{
     ArrayList students = new ArrayList();
     students.Add(student1);
}
```

Because a student is not a collection of students, and does not contain a collection of students.

One thing you can do, is to create a new class that represents a collection of students, let's call it `StudentProgram`:

```
public class StudentProgram
{
    private readonly List<Student> _students = new List<Student>();

    public StudentProgram(string programName)
    {
        Name = programName;
    }

    public readonly string Name;

    public void AddStudent(Student newStudent)
    {
        _students.Add(newStudent);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Student> AllStudents
    {
        get { return _students; }
    }
    public int NumberOfStudents
    {
        get { return _students.Count; }
    }
}
```

You can then use this in your `Main` like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    var scienceProgram = new StudentProgram("science");

    scienceProgram.Add(new Student(
        "John", "Grodinskiy", "12/07/1996", 
        "Lesy Ukrainky 88", "Cherkasy", "58000", "Ukraine"));
    scienceProgram.Add(new Student(
        "Niko", "Rekun", "03/02/1995", 
        "Promyslova 86", "Velykiy Bychkiv", "90615","Ukraine"));
    scienceProgram.Add(new Student(
        "Veronica","Kran", "26/03/1991", 
        "Uzhgorodska 1", "Svalyava", "59432", "Ukraine"));

    ........

    Console.WriteLine(
        "The {0} program has {1} students",
        scienceProgram.Name, scienceProgram.NumberOfStudents);

     foreach (var student in scienceProgram.AllStudents)
         student.TakeTest();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class Student:Person
    {
        public static List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();

        //....

        public static void add_student(Student newStudent)
        {             
             Students.Add(newStudent);
        }
    }
```

Students list is static it means you will have one list of students for the whole class, from the constructor and methods you have i think that is what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty confusing design, if you want to add students in the add_student method then you should use:

```
public void add_student(Student student)
{
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    students.Add(student);
}
```

Then in your main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    student1.Add(student1);
}
```

Adding students to a class called student doesn't make a lot of sense though (as you are passing student to itself which you could access with the 'this' keyword), if you explain the program further maybe I could help you improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following answer is just too simple. Maybe because I don't get your problem correctly. But if your problem lies here:

```
public void add_student()
    {
         ArrayList students = new ArrayList();
         students.Add(student1);
    }
```

So if you want to store new `students` into the `ArrayList students` then you could do the following:

```
ArrayList students = new ArrayList();
public void add_student(student1)
    {          
         students.Add(student1);
    }
```

And you can add `students`from your main class by:

```
Student person = new Student(...);
person.add_student("any student to be added");
```