# How to add stack to an object C#

Tags: c#

I would like to add a stack to a object I created but I don't know how to implement it.  Say I created 5 objects (students) and wanted to add a stack (grades) for each student object how would I do that ?

In my main method I have created a student object

```
 Student student1 = new Student

            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Wayne",
                BirthDate = "26/05/1907"


            };
```

I have another object course and add the students to it

```
            course.AddStudent(student1);
```

I have created a student object further down in the code

```
 public class Student : Person
    {
        public static int count = 0;

        // Stack of student grades
        Stack grades= new Stack();
       // Stack<int> grades = new Stack<int>();



        public Student()
        {
            // Thread safe since this is a static property
            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        }


        public void TakeTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Student takes test for course...");
        }

    }
```

How would I add a stack to each student object ?

Comment: Do you mean `List<Grade>`?

Comment: A stack is a LIFO (Last In, First Out) queue. Not what you would use for grades.

Comment: Lol, did you also start your homework late. Have a look at how far your class mate has progressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882335/how-to-call-make-visible-variable-from-another-class

Comment: its has to be a stack as its a test. Add 5 grades to the the Stack in the each Student object. (this does not have to be inside the constructor because you may not have grades for a student when you create a new student.)

Comment: If you really want a stack you could add a stack by deleting the `Stack grades= new Stack();` line, and uncommenting the line below that line.

Comment: I've almost got it below, i just don't know how to enter values to the stack for each student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `Student` `class` and add `Stack<int> Grades`
then in the `constructor` make an instance of `Grades Stack`

```
public class Student{
   //rest of properties
   public Stack<int> Grades { get; private set; }

   public Student()
   {
       //rest of the code
       Grades = new Stack<int>();
   }
}
```

Update 1:
To set the grade you could add new method to `Student class` to add grade

```
public void AddGrade(int grade)
{
    this.Grades.Push(grade);
}
```

more about `Stack<int>` [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stack)

Than after create Student object just call

```
student1.AddGrade(5) instead of student1.Grades.AddGrade(5)
```

Update 2:
In order to print the `Grades` values you should manually iterate the `Grades` stack in your `main` method

```
foreach(int grade in student1.Grades)
{
    Console.WriteLine(grade);
}
```

Comment: thats almost it, just one thing, how would I set the grade ?

Comment: how do I used the constructor to made an instance of Grades stack ? I already created a student object and don't how to add on grade ?***edit i get an error Program.Student.Grades' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @Aindriu this code call Student constructor and Grades instance is instantiated
            Student student1 = new Student
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Wayne",
                BirthDate = "26/05/1907"
            };

Comment: yes i got that bit... I can just add the line after student1.Grades.AddGrade(5); to add on grade BUT im getting an error due to protection level.. BUT its public

Comment: it prints out System.Collections.Generic.Stack'1[System.Int32] when I go Console.WriteLine(student1.Grades);

Comment: @Aindriu check Update 2

Comment: will try that now... how do I add 5 grades to the the Stack in the each Student object, i can only add 1 at the moment...still getting the object and not a grade print out

Comment: @Aindriu in order to add 5 grades, call the student1.AddGrade method 5 times